# Jfrog artifactory upgrade and clustering in docker-compose

Tags: artifactory

We are using self hosted Jfrog Artifactory version 6.20.0. It is single node infrastructure. We have hosted Docker-compose environment in single VM, where we are using nginx, artofactory-pro, Postgress DB containers.

Now we have plan to upgrade the Artifactory and convert it from standalone to cluster. I have following questions:

1. can we directly upgrade from version 6.20.0 to version Artifactory 7.31.13?
2. Any document or guidance to move from single node to cluster (active/active) of 2 nodes?
3. cluster in docker compose means each node has its own Postgres DB, Artifactory containers and then load balancer on top of two VMs containing these two containers. Did I understand it right or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, you can directly upgrade from 6.20.0 to 7.31.13.
2. Refer this JFrog [Confluence page](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Upgrading+Artifactory#UpgradingArtifactory-DockerComposeUpgrade) for the Artifactory upgrade.
3. Each node can not have its own DB, both the nodes will rely on single postgres database whereas the Artifactory load will be distributed between the nodes.

So the best approach for you is as below.

1. Perform an upgrade on single node first.
2. Once the upgrade is successful, you can just add the secondary node by connecting to the same database. Visit [this page](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Installing+Artifactory#InstallingArtifactory-HAInstallation), before adding the secondary node.
3. For adding node after visiting the requirements page, visit [this page](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Installing+Artifactory#InstallingArtifactory-DockerComposeHAInstallation) for adding another node for docker-compose method.

If you have any queries further/issues while upgrading or adding the node, you may reach JFrog Support.